Running 2 Different Angular Versions with 2 Different Node Versions Simultaneously
I am working on 2 Angular projects, first one with angular 14 and the second one with angular 18.
Now becuase each one requires a different node version, I'm using NVM to switch between node version, and because each Angular CLI is under a node version, I can only run one project at a time.
How to run both projects with different node versions at the same time on the same machine.


why exactly can't you run nvm, start the first project, run nvm again and then start the second project? 2) doesn't nvm respect a .nvmrc file to select the right version?

